# Karate framework - What is the correct way to use conditional logic "if-then-else" in scenario?

Tags: json, cucumber-jvm, karate

I tried couple of ways to make use of IF-Else conditional logic as mentioned in these two links   
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1r7ip.jpg) [How to check additional values with if condition (using karate framework)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669499/how-to-check-additional-values-with-if-condition-using-karate-framework)   
[2]https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic  
 After trying different combinations I am still unsuccessful and I don't see other ways to make my scenario work. For better visibility and understanding I have attached screenshot.  
[image: conditional logic issue in karate]

As shown both output2.c.data and z.d.data are empty array's. Using these two references I have defined     
 `*def output4 = (z.d.data == output2.c.data ? {pass:true} : {pass:false})` 
 I was expecting my output - **output4**- to be   `{"pass":true}` 
 For unknown reasons my scenario is giving me the opposite of what I am expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do an equals operation on two arrays in JavaScript, which is why Karate's "deep equals" `match` is needed.

```
* def foo = { data: [] } 
* def bar = { data: [] }

# wrong
* def result = foo.data == bar.data ? { pass: true } : { pass: false }
* match result == { pass: false }

# right
* def result = karate.match(foo.data, bar.data).pass ? { pass: true } : { pass: false }
* match result == { pass: true }
```

EDIT - this is a more detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475